# RuntimeException when Unmarshalling Android Intent Parcelable

Tags: android, arrays, list, arraylist, parcelable

I have an Object that I am passing between activities. In this Object there are seven variables. 
One of those variables is an ArrayList that is from another class.

I have implemented Parcelable on both.

**Here are the errors:**

> 09-08 17:00:04.212 18965-18965/it.sinesy.padova33 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: it.sinesy.padova33, PID: 18965
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.sinesy.padova33/org.thoughtcrime.securesms.ConversationListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@6e57f24: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274612 at offset 548
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@6e57f24: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274612 at offset 548
>           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2443)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2778)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:2035)
>           at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.util.ChatIntentParamenters.(ChatIntentParamenters.java:50)
>           at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.util.ChatIntentParamenters$1.createFromParcel(ChatIntentParamenters.java:80)
>           at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.util.ChatIntentParamenters$1.createFromParcel(ChatIntentParamenters.java:77)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2470)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2364)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2717)
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
>           at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:840)
>           at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:6239)
>           at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.ConversationListActivity.onCreate(ConversationListActivity.java:94)
>           at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.PassphraseRequiredActionBarActivity.onCreate(PassphraseRequiredActionBarActivity.java:48)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Here's my **ChatIntentParamenters** class parcelable code:

```
package org.thoughtcrime.securesms.util;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import org.thoughtcrime.securesms.contacts.PlatformContact;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ChatIntentParamenters implements Parcelable {
    public static final String FLAG_YES = "Y";
    public static final String FLAG_NO = "N";
    private String title;
    private String additionalTitle;
    private boolean canCreateGroups;
    private boolean canCreateMessages;
    private boolean canDeleteMessages;
    private boolean canInviteFriends;

    private ArrayList<PlatformContact> preloadedContacts;

    public ChatIntentParamenters(String title, String additionalTitle, boolean canCreateGroups, boolean canCreateMessages, boolean canDeleteMessages, boolean canInviteFriends, ArrayList<PlatformContact> preloadedContacts) {

        this.title = title;
        this.additionalTitle = additionalTitle;
        this.canCreateGroups = canCreateGroups;
        this.canCreateMessages = canCreateMessages;
        this.canDeleteMessages = canDeleteMessages;
        this.canInviteFriends = canInviteFriends;

        this.preloadedContacts = preloadedContacts;


    }

    public ChatIntentParamenters(Parcel parcel) {
        this.title = parcel.readString();
        this.additionalTitle = parcel.readString();

        this.canCreateGroups = parcel.readString().equals(FLAG_YES);
        this.canCreateMessages = parcel.readString().equals(FLAG_YES);
        this.canDeleteMessages = parcel.readString().equals(FLAG_YES);
        this.canInviteFriends = parcel.readString().equals(FLAG_YES);

        this.preloadedContacts = parcel.readArrayList(PlatformContact.class.getClassLoader());

    }



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(additionalTitle);

        dest.writeString(canCreateGroups?FLAG_YES:FLAG_NO);
        dest.writeString(canCreateMessages?FLAG_YES:FLAG_NO);
        dest.writeString(canDeleteMessages?FLAG_YES:FLAG_NO);
        dest.writeString(canInviteFriends?FLAG_YES:FLAG_NO);

        dest.writeList(preloadedContacts);

    }



    public final static Parcelable.Creator<ChatIntentParamenters> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ChatIntentParamenters>() {
        @Override
        public ChatIntentParamenters createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ChatIntentParamenters(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ChatIntentParamenters[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ChatIntentParamenters[size];
        }
    };


    public String getAdditionalTitle() {
        return additionalTitle;
    }

    public void setAdditionalTitle(String additionalTitle) {
        this.additionalTitle = additionalTitle;
    }

    public boolean isCanCreateGroups() {
        return canCreateGroups;
    }

    public void setCanCreateGroups(boolean canCreateGroups) {
        this.canCreateGroups = canCreateGroups;
    }

    public boolean isCanCreateMessages() {
        return canCreateMessages;
    }

    public void setCanCreateMessages(boolean canCreateMessages) {
        this.canCreateMessages = canCreateMessages;
    }

    public boolean isCanDeleteMessages() {
        return canDeleteMessages;
    }

    public void setCanDeleteMessages(boolean canDeleteMessages) {
        this.canDeleteMessages = canDeleteMessages;
    }

    public boolean isCanInviteFriends() {
        return canInviteFriends;
    }

    public void setCanInviteFriends(boolean canInviteFriends) {
        this.canInviteFriends = canInviteFriends;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ArrayList<PlatformContact> getPreloadedContacts() {
        return preloadedContacts;
    }

    public void setPreloadedContacts(ArrayList<PlatformContact> preloadedContacts) {
        this.preloadedContacts = preloadedContacts;
    }
}
```

and **PlatformContact**, my second class that is inserted as an ArrayList object into **ChatIntentParamenters**:

```
package org.thoughtcrime.securesms.contacts;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Classe per passare la lista dei contatti a signal, in modo che non li prenda dai contatti del telefono
 * Created by filippoboatto on 06/09/16.
 */

public class PlatformContact implements Parcelable {
    private long contactId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String imageURI;

    public PlatformContact (long contactId, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String imageURI){
        this.contactId = contactId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.imageURI = imageURI;
    }

    public PlatformContact(Parcel parcel) {
        this.contactId = parcel.readInt();
        this.firstName = parcel.readString();
        this.lastName = parcel.readString();
        this.phoneNumber = parcel.readString();
        this.imageURI = parcel.readString();
    }



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(contactId);
        dest.writeString(firstName);
        dest.writeString(lastName);
        dest.writeString(phoneNumber);
        dest.writeString(imageURI);
    }



    public final static Creator<PlatformContact> CREATOR = new Creator<PlatformContact>() {
        @Override
        public PlatformContact createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PlatformContact(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PlatformContact[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PlatformContact[size];
        }
    };
}
```

then use the following code to put an **ChatIntentParamenters** into the intent:

```
ChatIntentParamenters params = new ChatIntentParamenters(title, additionalTitle, canCreateGroups, canCreateMessages, canDeleteMessages, false, contactsList);
intent.putExtra(ConversationListActivity.INTENT_PARAMS, params);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

I have the error when I get intent extra in the activity:

```
ChatIntentParamenters params = intent.getParcelableExtra(INTENT_PARAMS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
this.preloadedContacts = parcel.readArrayList(PlatformContact.class.getClassLoader())
```

with

```
    this.preloadedContacts= new ArrayList<>();
    parcel.readTypedList(this.preloadedContacts, PlatformContact.CREATOR);
```

and

```
    dest.writeList(preloadedContacts);
```

with

```
    dest.writeTypedList(preloadedContacts)
```

Comment: Ok now I have the **ArrayList<PlatformContact>** but when I read it with **getParcelableExtra**, the 'PlatformContact' in the array list have only the first property with a value, the others are null:
`ChatIntentParamenters params = intent.getParcelableExtra(INTENT_PARAMS);`


In the **PlatformContact** parcelable class, when I write on writeToParcel all the properties are set.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your are writing the `contactId` as a long(64-bit) and are reading it as an int (32-bit), I don't see anything else being wrong. If that's not it, can you confirm that you actually have values in those fields when you are creating the Parcelable?

Comment: changed the write of contactId from int to long but the other properties are still null

Comment: I updated the original answer - changed the way the list is written into `Parcel`

Comment: Removed Parcelable, now I use JSON strings, putExtra and getStringExtra...it works :-)